Exposing dependencies results in "fat" constructor. What should you do next?
You take a non-testable class with a lot of static dependencies and expose, and expose until they are all explicitly declared in a constructor
But halfway through that nice plan, you notice your constructor gets big. Having many args in a function (let's see constructors as a special type of function) is bad too
Some may suggest the builder pattern, but I'm still not 100% convinced one is allowed to throw in the build() method (all of those dependencies are mandatory)
What should you do?
The standard advice is, "When your constructor gets big, it means the class has a lot of responsibilities, split it". But I don't see how I can split it! It really needs all of those
We have a dialog class that deals with vaccines (it is a bit like a form that a nurse fills in before administering a vaccine, I reckon). It had a lot of static calls that performed DB operations (still has). I moved some of those dependencies to the constructor(s), and now it already has three dependencies beside string ids (I'll omit those)
    public VacDlg(VaccineDao vaccineDao, InfectionDao infectionDao, VaccinationDao vaccinationDao) {

I may go on, and it'll also have SchemeDao, ActDao, maybe even SexDao
If we used Hibernate or a similar framework, I could retrieve all the data with fewer DAOs (maybe, even one) as DAOs (repositories) would be connected to each other similarly to how the corresponding tables are. But we don't
And by the way, if you wonder why a dialog class has dependencies on DAOs at all, it's because we don't have a clear separation between the frontend, backend, and data layers. The frontend communicates with the DB directly. The backend code mostly resides in the DB but also in the frontend
And those are just DAOs. I'm sure it has other hidden dependencies as well
That's going to be a lot of args! I don't want to replace one mess with mess of another kind

Next, you should take the fat constructor as a signal, an indicator telling you that your class is trying to do too much on its own, and decompose it, so that it delegates the details of various tasks to a couple of smaller classes with a more narrowly defined job; with these few classes replacing your old dependencies. Then go down one level and repeat if needed.

@FilipMilovanović can you be more liberal with the specifics?

I left a comment as I don't have time to write a full answer (maybe later), but the idea is to find bits of functionality within this class that make sense on their own. Are there code blocks topped with an explanatory comment? - that could be a function. Are there are functions that only access a subset of the dependencies? That could be a separate class, etc. The end goal is to reduce your current class to something that "orchestrates" the calls to a small number of these other classes, and almost reads like a list of high-level tasks. The extracted classes would be doing the actual work.

You seem to be injecting repositories in what appears to be a frontend component. That suggest that the responsibility of your "dialog" component is much, much deeper than what a "dialog" is.
I can't even see its implementation and by your description of its signature alone it appears that this is responsible for the entire interaction from the user's input down to it being persisted in the database, with only a repository layer inbetween.
The issue here should not be a concern about the amount of dependencies being injected and the syntax that follows from it. Your concern here should be about the amount of responsibilities that you're baking into this single class.
The number of dependencies required in this class is merely a symptom of the disease.
It appears you're already aware of this:

And by the way, if you wonder why a dialog class has dependencies on DAOs at all, it's because we don't have a clear separation between the frontend, backend, and data layers.

But you seem to be taking the stance that acknowledging it somehow resolves it as being a problem. It doesn't. The problem you're pointing at here stems from you expecting the dialog class to also orchestrate everything down to the persistence layer.

Additionally, and this is really not the main thing you should be focusing on but still relevant to point out; the issue that "avoid methods with too many parameters" points out is one of complexity for the developer who has to write the consuming code that calls those methods.
Dependency injection tends to happen via a container that acts as an automatic factory that looks at the constructor's parameters and resolves those dependencies automatically, thereby completely sidestepping the need for humans to call the constructor themselves in most cases (other than your test suite, but that's a separate topic).

Thank you. I can't think of any practical takeaway form your answer, though. I clearly can't create a whole new backend layer on my own

@SergeyZolotarev, if your architecture doesn't follow best practices, then you cannot expect to be able to follow all best practices in the code either. You will basically have to live with an uncomfortable high number of arguments to the constructor.

@SergeyZolotarev What Bart said. You're correct that just because something is better does not mean that you can singlehandedly will it into existence. But knowing that the issue is there should resolve your concern about e.g. having too many method params (and other minor style guidelines). Those guidelines are given in the assumption that the listener is able to make the necessary change. If that's not the case for you, then you can't hold yourself to those guidelines because you simply can't effect the change that they're telling you to make.

I exposed a few more DAOs (DB calls used to be embedded in the dialog class itself). Now, the dialog has four DAOs, and I could make it five: vaccine DAO, vaccination DAO, disease DAO (actually, the DB table was named wrong: it contains infections, not diseases), act DAO, scheme DAO. Add three id strings, and you get 8. Maybe, for a lack of a better option, I should wrap those DAOs in some VacService and expose some delegating methods?

@SergeyZolotarev: We seem to be going in circles here. Refactoring the existing set of responsibilities (without changing that division of responsibilities) cannot resolve the amount of code you need to write due to having way too many responsibilities stacked in a single class. Your mention of "wrapping it in a service", while that would provide additional abstraction, does not fill me with hope that you'll be designing this service with the right spirit, instead just using it to hide lengthy code away from sight.

The dialog, one way or another, have to perform DB calls, no matter the number of abstraction layers between the dialog and the DB. It's because the content of the dialog is dynamic, it should be updated on certain user interactions. So that responsibility stays there, there's no apparent way around it. What I can do is adding an extra layer of abstraction (or a few). Don't you think it's a good idea?

@SergeyZolotarev: Your last comment indicates that you are conflating the concept of composition and nesting, and are treating them interchangeably. I don't know how to steer you out of this interpretation. What I was trying to point out is that abstractions have to be made for the right reason, otherwise the design goes off the rails. Creating a service for the purpose of reducing constructor parameter count is doing the (generally) right thing for the wrong reason. I suggest you stop trying to remodel what you have, and instead design it the right way from the ground up before you continue.

@Flater can you be more specific?

You are missing the ViewModel layer I mentioned in my last answer.
VaccineDialogueViewModel
{
   Vaccine vaccine
   Infection infection
   Vaccination vaccination
}

Now you can populate this in your (client side) controller and pass to the Dialogue component
Also, please lose the DAOs
tbh though, I think you are doing something wrong in the larger methodology of your programming, which we haven't been shown. It might be that you are trying to apply MVC or MVVM to a framework which isn't designed to support them.

How is the model going to get the data?

"you can populate this in your (client side) controller"? I think we need to see the whole of your code, not these snippets

Wouldn't that controller face the very same problem?

presumably it either uses DI to get stuff or instantates as required. you dont show the whole code

But you're going to DI those very same dependencies, aren't you?

the top layer of your code has to have everything. But you don't need or want to pass them down to every random UI control. You should get the data needed for the screen or page at the top level and then populate the UI. When you have events like clicks, these should bubble back up to the top and be dealt with there, where you have access to all the services etc

What you seem to be doing is passing your service or data layer into your UI controls. But you will have UI Controls nested in other UI controls all over the place, you will end up having to inject everything into everything. Don't program like that
